# Ruby on Rails - Is it possible to remove the "template tree digest" from a cache key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

We are implementing a "reactive" cache that for the most part keeps every important object cached at all times and only updates these objects on updates/creates. We are using jbuilder to render most of the json we interact with https://github.com/rails/jbuilder. They've included very straight forward caching mirroring that of view fragment caching.

My issue is this - when storing the cached object i need to be using retrievable keys so we can delete them after any model updates. Which seemed easy at first.... but has caused trouble. Rails.cache.delete_matcher doesn't seem to be working and the same goes with passing a regex into expire_fragment.

So the only solution I can see is being able to remove the "template tree digest" from the end of the cache key.

[image: Link here]

Real world example would be converting

> jbuilder/v3/users/38-20170809004706672937000/performers/1493168-20170823184135817877000/d84abdae117cd787b8204fd744e7dc06

to

> jbuilder/v3/users/38-20170809004706672937000/performers/1493168-20170823184135817877000

(bye bye d84abdae117cd787b8204fd744e7dc06)

This would make the key easy to replicate and therefore delete.
Is this even possible? Am I missing the importance of including this key? Any help would be very much appreciate!!! I'm dying over her

Comment: "The template digest that's added to the cache key is computed by taking an md5 of the contents of the entire template file. This ensures that your caches will automatically expire when you change the template file." - still think removing it is a good idea?

Comment: A better idea altogether is to use E-Tags and a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the skip_digest option to all your caching

ex.

json.cache! ['v1', venue], expires_in: 12.hours, :skip_digest => true  do
    json.partial! "venues/venue", venue: venue
end

That removes the cache digest from the end of the cache key

more here

https://reinteractive.com/posts/197-if-you-explicitly-expire-cached-fragments-opt-out-of-cache-digests